# Sum columns of a large .txt or .csv Linux

Tags: linux, csv

I have a very large `.txt`. I need to manipulate the data to find out how much information is stored. I essentially need to sum up all the individual points of data. The problem is that all of the data is stored in columns and I'm not sure how to run Linux commands to properly sum it all.

Part of the file:

```
header:                                                                 
  seq: 0                                                                
  stamp:                                                                
    secs: 1467830307                                                                
    nsecs: 890825036                                                                
  frame_id: map                                                             
info:                                                               
  map_load_time:                                                                
    secs: 0                                                             
    nsecs:         0                                                                
  resolution: 0.0500000007451                                                               
  width: 7200                                                               
  height: 7200                                                              
  origin:                                                               
    position:                                                               
      x: -180.0                                                             
      y: -180.0                                                             
      z: 0.0                                                                
    orientation:                                                                
      x: 0.0                                                                
      y: 0.0                                                                
      z: 0.0                                                                
      w: 1.0                                                                
data: [0    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 ]
```

The actual file is a much much larger than this, but essentially I need to add all of the numbers within that 'data' set (everything else can be deleted). 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please format your question so we can understand what your file looks like. Does it actually have a line that reads "Header:" or "Data:"? If not could just paste a sample of the file. A few records. And format it as code so we can read it.

Comment: Sorry, I think it should be a bit easier to see now. Everything (header, info, ect.) is part of the actual file. I was thinking of just deleting that and only have the data line, and then try to sum that.

Comment: Is the `data` always the last thing in the file? Is the data always the only thing within `[...]` in the file?

Comment: Yes, to both of those questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your file is called `data.txt`, I would use `awk` like this:

```
awk '
   /^data:/ {f=1}
   f==1     {gsub(/[a-zA-Z:\[\]]/,""); for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)t+=$i}
   END      {print t}
' data.txt
```

That reads your file `data.txt` one line at a time. If it finds the word `data:` at the start of a line, it sets a flag `f` so it *"knows"* it has got past all the stuff at the start of the file and it needs to start totalling the numbers.

The next part only looks at lines after the word `data:` because it is prefixed with the condition `f==1`. That removes all letters, colons and square brackets from the line using `gsub()`. It then loops through all fields on the line (`NF` is the number of fields) and totals up the elements in a variable called `t`.

At the end of the file, the section starting with `END` runs and it prints the total.

You can write it all on one line like this if you prefer:

```
awk '/^data:/{f=1} f==1{gsub(/[a-zA-Z:\[\]]/,"");for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)t+=$i} END{print t}' data.txt
```

Comment: When you delete all letters, does it recompute NF? otherwise the line starting with data will be misaligned with the next lines (ie,the "data" lines will have their value in "column+1" compared to the lines without data at the start...) (iow, the first 0 in the example is in column 2, and also col1 will also be interpreted as 0! )

Comment: sorry, didn't understood that the op just need a flat addition of all, and not a sum per columns... (where my previous comment would need to be taken into account. here you are fine, and the addition of "" ($1, formerly "data") will just add 0 to the sum, so the result is correct. +1